# Iterate hexadecimals to create jpeg files

Tags: python, image, hex

I have a textfile with lines of hexadecimals. I want each line to transform into a jpeg.file because they are photos. I can do that individually using binascii.a2b_hex like this (I've shortened the hex):

```
data = binascii.a2b_hex("FFD8FFE")
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as image_file:
    #image_file.write(data)
```

Now I want to this in bulk. So I have a textfile with lines of hexadecimals and I want each hexadecimal to write to his own jpeg file. I think I'm almost there but my code gives me this error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Here is the code:

```
import binascii
text_file = open("photos-clean.txt", "w")

#for each hexadecimal, put it in between single quotes so it becomes a string. Also remove the first two chars from a line.
with open('photos.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        photo = i[2:]
        quotes = "'" + photo.rstrip() + "'"
        print quotes
        text_file.write(quotes)
        text_file.write("\n")

text_file.close()

#for each hexadecimal, transform it to a jpeg with binascii and write it to his own jpeg.file
with open("photos-clean.txt", "r") as f2:
    for i, data in (f2):
        transform = binascii.a2b_hex(i)
        with open('photo{}.jpg'.format(transform), 'wb') as output:
            output.write(data)
```

Edit: I have the answer and this is what I should've done:

```
import binascii
text_file = open("photos-clean.txt", "w")


with open('photos.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i in f:
        photo = i[2:]
        text_file.write(photo)
        text_file.write("\n")

text_file.close()


with open("photos-clean.txt", "r") as f2:
    count=0
    for i in f2:
        count = count + 1
        cleaned = i.strip("\r\n")
        transform = binascii.a2b_hex(cleaned)
        with open("{}.jpg".format(count), 'wb') as output:
            output.write(transform)
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are having error at line `for i, data in (f2):`.
You try to unpack 2 value i and data from f2, i guess you need enumerate as below.
Also, i assume you wanna use i as index to the filename and write the transform instead of data into output

```
with open("photos-clean.txt", "r") as f2:
    for i, data in enumerate(f2):
        transform = binascii.a2b_hex(data)
        with open('photo{}.jpg'.format(i), 'wb') as output:
            output.write(transfrom)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I have changed it to your way and it gives me now a different error: Too many values to unpack. Any idea what could be? I have removed the enumerate because I don't want to alter the hexadecimals.

Comment: Not clear on what you want,  enumerate is not alter the hexadecimal,  without enumerate, u can, t get i and data,  will have error

Comment: I want each line in the file, which is a hex, to be transformed to a jpeg. I have 70 lines so I want to see 70 jpegs in my folder. I don't know why it works individually but in a batch it fails.

Comment: Have u try exactly my code without removing the enumerate?

Comment: Yes I have. Then I get: TypeError: Odd-length string. It looks he is struggling with the hex-strings. They are very long but it works if I do them one by one.